# How to correctly add resources to a project?

Tags: xcode, resources, makefile, cmake, share

I have a project organized as follows:

- `include/`
- `src/`
- `share/myprogram/`

where `share/myprogram/` contains resources.
My program is accessing these resources using relative paths. The executable expects to find them in `../share/myprogram/`.

I would like when I run:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

to have the following to happen:

- make a `bin` directory
- compile and put the executable in `bin/`
- copy the `share` directory in the `build` directory

**I am looking for a clean way of doing this. Ideally, I would like CMake to be *aware* of the resources *as resources*.**
I know that I could use a copy custom command. Is this the only way to achieve this?

#### Bonus

If the resources could appear under *Resources* in Xcode when using the Xcode generator, and the copy be a clean copy phase under the mybin target, that would be awesome (and that's what I mean by CMake being aware of the resources *as resources*.)

---

#### Update:

What I have thus far:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_executable(mybin ${Headers} ${Sources})

add_custom_target(
    Resources ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/share ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/share
    SOURCES ${Resources}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing a unix command line tool, I am not doing a Mac OS X bundle and Xcode's resource folder is only for bundle resources so forget the bonus.

I realized that I wasn't doing things correctly.
Using a relative path to access a resource is not reliable since the program can be executed from anywhere.
What I did is to look for resources in a hierarchy of folder, starting from user specified, to environment variable, to relative directories and finally to standard unix directories.

So actually, the copy phase during the build is not necessary anymore. Only the installation matters and that is fairly easy:

```
install(DIRECTORY share/ DESTINATION share)
```

FYI, I kept my `custom_target` as is since I like having resources visible in Xcode, and calling it `Resources` makes it pretty :)

Comment: Well I got one serious problem with having the resources visible in Xcode - if they are are fairly large in size, Xcode does some nasty processing and shows "hourglass" icon when I try to e.g. change build target in the drop-down menu of the IDE. The larger the resoruces are, the longer Xcode "thinks", preventing me from doing anything else. I noticed that the resources are registered as "source" in the .pbxproj file, unlik regular resources (added manually through IDE), which are registered in slightly different way.

Answer (score 2):

You may use **Configure_file** for copying files from source dir to binary dir. it has parameter **Copyonly**.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried that within a `foreach` and it did the copy just fine. However the files don't appear in the project (in Xcode for instance) so I think I prefer the custom_target so far. One good point of your method is that you don't use `cp`.

Comment: Actually, I replaced `cp -r` by `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory`.